# Is it possible to schedule the execution of daily macros in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ssis, ms-access-2016

There are a couple of macros that need to be executed everyday at a fixed time. I am not an expert of MS Access but have been assigned to do this task. I was told that it can be done using SSIS Packages built in Visual studio. Can someone please tell me ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to create an Access database, add a form that is loaded when the database is opened, and use the "OnOpen" event to run the assorted pieces of code required before exiting the database using `Application.Quit`.

This database should be placed on a server, as it will be on 24/7.

You would then use Windows Task scheduler on the server to create a recurring task to open this database (which then causes the code to run).

You may want to include some logging/reporting/email notification in the code to allow you to keep track of whether the actions have failed or not.

Regards,

Comment: I do not have an option to use Windows Task Scheduler. Is there anyway it can be done without it?

Comment: You could "kludge" something together using a form's Timer event, but Task Scheduler is the way to do it.